# Not accepted binary during upload to App Store Connect

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to upload a new release from my iOS app to App Store Connect, but I am getting always an error message while uploading the binary.

Here you have the error message:

[image]

I have created the new release version in App Store Connect, as always:

[image]

And as far as I know there is not version "9" anywhere.

Here you have a screenshot from the app identity panel from Xcode.

[image]

What am I doing wrong. I am not doing anything not done before to upload a new release from the app.

Comment: What's the latest available version on the App Store right now? And what builds have you uploaded for version 2.1 so far?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth, the latest available version on the app store is 1.52. And this is the first build for version 2.1 (60)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the version number and build number before uploading to app store.

-Version number you should increment when your previous version is live and ready for sale.
-Build number you have to increment when previous build is failed after uploading.
-Every time you have to give new build id increment by one. e.g Your version is 2. so can have build : 2.0,2.1,2.2 and so on.

For your case version 2.1 is closed for previous release either you can use 2.2 or 3.0. and for build you can use 61.